# How to only trigger a function when window width is less than a certain amount?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have created a simple accordion for some footer content that I only want to trigger when the window width is less than 600px. I've tried using window.resize but when resizing the window above 600px the function is still initialising and I can't understand why.

If anyone would mind sharing some advice on this I'd really appreciate it. I keep going round in circles.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/597ghbm6/)

JS:

```
function initializeAccordion() {
  var mainToggle = $('.footer-accordion > .footer-column > p');
  $('.footer-accordion > .footer-column > .menu').css('display', 'none');

  mainToggle.click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var secondLevel = $(this).siblings('.menu');
    var allSeconds = $('.footer-accordion > .footer-column > .menu');

    if (that.hasClass('is-active')) {
      secondLevel.slideUp();
      that.removeClass('is-active');
      mainToggle.removeClass('is-active');
      allSeconds.removeClass('is-active');
      allSeconds.slideUp();
    } else {
      mainToggle.removeClass('is-active');
      allSeconds.removeClass('is-active');
      allSeconds.slideUp();
      secondLevel.slideDown();
      that.addClass('is-active');
      secondLevel.addClass('is-active');
    }
  });
};

if ($(window).width() < 600) {
  initializeAccordion();
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 600) {
    initializeAccordion();
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to write the `else` conditions in your `if` statements to reset the accordion state when the page is `> 600px` wide. It does not happen automatically. That being said, as all you're doing is amending some classes and performing some animations I'd strongly suggest you use CSS media queries for this instead of JS. They will perform orders of magnitude faster, and be smoother.

Comment: Ok but can you explain why the click event still fires when resizing from say 400px up to 800px?

Comment: Because you attached the event when the page loads and do not unbind it. Use `off()` to do that

Comment: Oh I see! Ok thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A pure JS cross-browser solution:

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  checkWidth();
}
checkWidth();

function checkWidth() {
  var vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
  if (vw < 600) {
    //callFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: Another downvote because it does not relate to the question in any useful way

Comment: I changed the background toggle to function. Hope that clears that up.